# Android koush/ion lib unable to post and receive JSON response

Tags: android, android-networking, android-ion, ion-koush

I am using ION to GET/POST for REST and also to get Images into ListView
but I am unable to use POST method and receive response as a JSON
The ION version that I am using is 1.3.7. Tested on emulator and also on real devices 4.1.1, 4.2.2 and 4.4

[ION Link on gitHub](https://github.com/koush/ion)

This code is called on a button click to post to the server after the validations are successful. This is inside support fragment v4:20 defined in  gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'

///////////////////

Ion.with(getActivity())
    .load(URLStr)
    .addQuery("action", "dummyAction")
    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .setLogging("ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING", Log.VERBOSE)
    .setJsonObjectBody(jsonStr)
    .asJsonObject()
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
        if (null != e) {
            if (null != result) {

                Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "JSON Result User basic Info: " + result);
            } else {
                Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "error in posting User basic Info");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "error in posting User basic Info", e);
        }
    }
    });
```

I am getting NullPointer at result. 
The request JSON is also valid, and I am using GSON to construct it.
The response JSON is valid as I checked it using POSTMAN chrome app.

However, below code works perfectly fine, but it's depricated ION.with(getActivity(), URL)
So I dont know, where am I making mistake.

```
    Ion.with(getActivity(), URLStr)
            .addQuery("action", "dummyAction")
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    if (e != null) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error loading user data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "DATA: " + result.toString());
                    String data = result.get("status").getAsString();
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "DATA: " + data);
                }
            });
```

Below is the verbose output from the first call

```
    08-12 14:18:06.010  27928-27928/com.abc.xyz: D/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (0 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: preparing request
    08-12 14:18:06.010  27928-27928/com.abc.xyz: I/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (0 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: Using loader: com.koushikdutta.ion.loader.HttpLoader@42d0e6c8
    08-12 14:18:06.025  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: D/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (0 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: Executing request.
    08-12 14:18:06.040  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: I/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (14 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: Response may be served from conditional cache
    08-12 14:18:06.040  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: V/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (16 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: Resolving domain and connecting to all available addresses
    08-12 14:18:06.195  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: V/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (167 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: socket connected
    08-12 14:18:06.195  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: V/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (169 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction:
        GET /service.php?post=stepOne HTTP/1.1
        Host: 188.226.224.99
        User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; GT-N7000 Build/KTU84P)
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
        Connection: keep-alive
        Accept: */*
        Content-Type: application/json
        If-Modified-Since: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 06:42:34 UTC
    08-12 14:18:06.200  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: V/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (170 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: request completed
    08-12 14:18:06.355  27928-27928/com.abc.xyz: D/MatchBot﹕ DATA: {"status":"pending"}
    08-12 14:18:06.370  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: V/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (347 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: Received headers:
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 08:48:08 GMT
        Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
        X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11
        Vary: Accept-Encoding
        Content-Encoding: gzip
        Content-Length: 64
        Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Type: text/html
    08-12 14:18:06.380  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: D/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (355 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: Caching response
    08-12 14:18:06.380  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: V/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (356 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: Final (post cache response) headers:
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 08:48:08 GMT
        Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
        X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11
        Vary: Accept-Encoding
        Content-Encoding: gzip
        Content-Length: 64
        Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
        Connection: Keep-Alive
        Content-Type: text/html
    08-12 14:18:06.380  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: D/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (356 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: Connection successful
    08-12 14:18:06.385  27928-27928/com.abc.xyz: E/MatchBot﹕ error in posting User basic Info
    08-12 14:18:06.390  27928-28187/com.abc.xyz: D/ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING﹕ (364 ms) http://urlHidden/service.php?action=dummyAction: Recycling keep-alive socket
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by riinav on 17/6/14.
 */
public class User implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("facebook_id")
    private String userFBId;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String registrationStatus;

    private transient Date registeredOnDate;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String userFBId, String registrationStatus) {
    this.userFBId = userFBId;
    this.registrationStatus = registrationStatus;
    }

    /* 
     * getters, setters and overidden equals and hashcode methods
     */
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by riinav on 27/6/14.
 */
public class UserBasicInfo extends User {//implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String userName;

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String emailId;

    @SerializedName("gender")
    private String gender;

    @SerializedName("bday")
    private String dob;

    @SerializedName("country")
    private String country;

    @SerializedName("city")
    private String city;

    @SerializedName("self_image")
    private String profilePicUrl;

    @SerializedName("school")
    private String school;

    @SerializedName("college")
    private String college;

    @SerializedName("degree")
    private String qualification;

    @SerializedName("sorientation")
    private String sexualPreference;

    @SerializedName("prefered_age")
    private String preferedAge;

    @SerializedName("prefered_city")
    private String preferedCity;

    public UserBasicInfo() {
    super();
    }

    /* 
     * getters, setters and overidden equals and hashcode methods
     */
}

/////////////////////////////////////// User Model json posted to server

User: {
    "college": "University of Mumbai,",
    "bday": "01/01/1980",
    "email": "dummyEmail@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "degree": "college degree",
    "school": "abc High School,",
    "name": "awesome name",
    "status": "PROCESS",
    "facebook_id": "000000000000000" // test fbId
}

 ///////////////// Server expected response 

 onSuccess:
 {"status":"success"}

 OnError:
 {"status":"error MESSAGE”}
```

Comment: What is the type on jsonStr? Can you provide a url with some sample data I can look at?

Comment: jsonStr is a String representation of JSON, converted using GSON  <br/>       `UserBasicInfo user = createUser();

        //JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonStr = gson.toJson(user);`   <br/> where UserBasicInfo class is a POJO  <br/>    `user.setUserName("xx"); etc

Comment: Don't pass in the string, pass in the POJO object directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the POJO object directly. Ion will automatically serialize it into JSON for you.

Comment: I tried it and it's still giving me same error.  <br/> My POJO is `public class UserBasicInfo extends User implements Serializable { } `   ` public class User implements Serializable { } `

Comment: An actual stack trace of this exception you are receiving would be helpful. And also the class definition as well, if you can provide that. The exception may be enough though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put together a test case. Any chance you can share the stack trace of the error you are seeing? I don't see one in what you pasted.

Comment: Hi, Koush, I added the stackTrace, this is the only log which is getting printed.

Comment: I don't see a log of a stack trace. Also, your logging is backwards.

Should be:
   if (null != e) {
            if (null != result) {

                Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "JSON Result User basic Info: " + result);
            } else {
                Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "error in posting User basic Info", e);
            }
        } else {


You're missing the exception itself when logging it.

Comment: Basically, the log you showed indicates an exception (null != e), but you are not printing it.

Comment: Hi Koush, I changed as you suggested and it worked fine. I was expecting that server should send errors in Exception parameter, but instead it sent errors in response result itself. **Thanks for pointing out the logical error.** It helped me track down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use method as argument to load

```
Ion.with(getActivity())
   .load("POST",URLStr)
   .addQuery("action", "dummyAction")
   .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
   .setLogging("ION_VERBOSE_LOGGING", Log.VERBOSE)
   .setJsonObjectBody(jsonStr)
   .asJsonObject()
   .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
       @Override
       public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {}
   });
```