# Android : Is it possible to send a Json Body and a Zip file by Content-Type", "multipart/mixed using HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, json, http, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data

I need to use the  **Content-Type", "multipart/mixed** and send the Json Body as `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` and also a file by a Request param `"file"` by `"Content-Type: text/xml"`, can any body explain how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to send both, i hope you may have sent ever image as file to server.

Answer (score 0):

For file upload/download, I always rely on [ION](https://github.com/koush/ion), an Android Asynchronous Networking library. You can refer to one of the [sample](https://github.com/koush/ion#post-json-and-read-json) provided by developer to achieve your goal.

I have modified the sample for your reference, but the settings may differ according to your backend configuration.

```
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
body.put("Your key", "Your value");

Ion.with(getContext())
.load("https://koush.clockworkmod.com/test/echo")
.setMultipartParameter("body", body.toString()) // this your jsonBody
.setMultipartFile("file", "application/zip", new File(your file path))
.asJsonObject() // if you want to receive response in json, use this.
.setCallback(...)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but .setMultipartFile("file", "application/zip", new File("/sdcard/filename.zip")) is not accepted when .setJsonObjectBody(body) is added

Comment: You can try this option. Instead using setJsonObjectBody, you can use setMultiPartParameter.  
...
.setMultipartParameter("body", body.toString())
.setMultipartFile("file", "application/zip", new File("/sdcard/filename.zip")). Check the modified answer

Comment: thank you, but here i do not have a any "key" to pass it as a string. I need to pass the json as a request body. Once please have a look at  this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975099/how-resttemplate-supports-for-multipart-mixed-in-consumption  you may get idea about my requirement.

Comment: I am quite confuse with your requirement. If you want to sent Content-Type, it is not necessarily in JSON. You also can use setMultipartParameter("Content-Type", "application/json") or you can put it in header, like this .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"). You can refer this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153340/android-koush-ion-lib-unable-to-post-and-receive-json-response